# How to let the parent window of a child window (a.k.a. owned window) stay active with winapi?

Tags: c, winapi, parent

I am writing a small C application using winapi. There I've got a window with a child window (toolbox). I am able to keep it inside this window and so on, but my question is: How to keep the main window active, if the child window gets focused?

The main window gets grayed out in this moment.

The windows get created by:

```
hMainWindow = DialogBoxParam(.......);
hChildWindow = CreateDialogParam(..., hMainWindow, ...); 
ShowWindow (hChildWindow, SW_SHOW);
```

Here a little image of the behaviour of the two windows:

[image: The behaviour of the windows]

Comment: AFAIK the active window is the one that has focus, so if the child has focus, then the main window cannot also have focus.

Comment: Maybe not in this way, but i know other applications like - you may know - Paint.NET it is possible.

Comment: You may want to define what you mean by "active" then? Are you using MDI windows?

Comment: I am not using MDI windows. (No idea how to do that in C) And "active" = not grayed out like an inactive window.

Comment: If seen Paint.NET do this.  Nasty hacks, it filters Windows messages to convince the window that it is still active so it doesn't redraw the caption bar.  I don't remember the exact details well enough to repro it here.  Source code is no longer available, maybe you can dig up an old copy somewhere.  Consider a caption-less tool window instead where you draw a simulated caption bar in the client area.

Comment: Oh, and technically, the tool window is not a child window.  It's an owned window, which is different in some key ways.  Unfortunately, the terminology is often misused, even in MSDN.

Comment: Okay so how can I create an owned window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out that simply creating it as `WS_CHILD` and explicitly **NOT** as `WS_POPUP` solves that. It also turns the absolute window coordinates to relative ones so that I dont have to care about the window position anymore by moving the parent window.

// Solved

Answer (score 1):

Create the child window as a modeless dialog box instead of a modal one. So instead of using [DialogBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), use [CreateDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I already do that.
hPanel = CreateDialogParam(......);
ShowWindow (hPanel, SW_SHOW);

Comment: Well then I don't understand the question I guess. You can only have one 'active' window. The topmost window is always the focused one.

Comment: @Mike Kwan's answer has always worked for me. Do you mean you can't select the parent window at all? Or do you mean you just don't want the child window to be focused at all when it's created?

Comment: I've did a little scetch of it. May you now understand the problem a little bit better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that's just the way Windows works:  one active window at a time.

You can see this in Visual Studio if you bring up Find and Replace as a tool window, you'll see that it gets activated and the main VS window goes inactive.

Trying to have them both active at the same time could confuse users and accessibility tools like screen readers.

Comment: Yes  you are right, may I should make it a panel, but a panel in C I would do in the same way, as a captionless window. So the problem remains. or is there an other possiblity?